# Eclipse RCP Spring Framework java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for classes

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP project, and after changing new Spring plugins and other plugins, I got a bunch of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. The project compiled with no errors...

What did I miss?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:131)
   ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar:na]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
   ~[org.springframework.core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
   ~[org.springframework.beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
   ~[org.springframework.beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
   ~[org.springframework.beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app configuration (clicking on debug icon and then the arrow to show the dialog) make sure that plugin is checked, in the plugin.xml that contains the Spring class make sure in the runtime tab of the plugin editor the package is listed in the exported packages view. If you have done all that comment and we can try some more things.

Comment: Thanks...Yes, I tried these steps already, but it doesn't work...  Got it to work after add Eclipse-BuddyPolicy:Registered, ext, global